# IcoMoon Not loading properly

Tags: css, extjs, sencha-touch-2, ios-simulator, sencha-architect

Using Sencha Architect 2  with Sencha Touch 2.2.1

I have followed this tutorial, my code is exactly the same :

https://vimeo.com/66191690

Because I'm trying to use icoMoon Icons/Font into my app.

Yet even if it compiles correctly, if i set an iconCLS to a newly include icoMoon icon name...
There is nothing appearing at all.

ICONCLS is set to plane for the Projects Tab. I used the default character for the plane icon which is '!'. Didnt change anything on icomoon, it's all default properties on this font sample.

[image: Everything]

[image: Inspector]

Comment: Please post some code or create a fiddle

Comment: Added code even though it is the same has the video

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first attribute in the `icon-font` mixin is the `font-family`, and in the case of IcoMoon, that value is `IcoMoon` (which is set in the video.

So your SASS file should look like this:

```
@import 'sencha-touch/default';
@import 'sencha-touch/default/all';

@include icon-font('IcoMoon', inline-font-files('pictos/icomoon.woff', woff, 'pictos/icomoon.ttf', truetype, 'pictos/icomoon.svg', svg));

@include icon('plane', 't', 'IcoMoon');
```

Changing the file name is fine, however changing the `font-family` (which is set in the font file itself) is not.

Comment: I will check on the font family thing, but hmmm i'm pretty sure when I dled the font I had also set the font family to Test. Will give you feedback monday  Thank You!

Comment: It didn't work see my updated question with SS of what I have

Comment: Very strange, as normally if the font is not loaded, it would simply display the text character. You will need to inspect the element using Web inspector in the browser and see what the problem is.

Comment: Screenshot of the inspector, might have found something but still can't understand what's going on ?  Seems to be a Pictos FOnt Family and not IconMoon

Comment: OKay I found something even weirder...  It does not show in chrome or safari... but in IOS simulator it does work... why?

Comment: Is the `content` CSS property being set on the :before element in the inspector? I see the font-family being set, but cannot see `content`. Perhaps a caching issue?

Comment: It doesnt seem to be set. What do you mean caching issue? (im using local storage fine atm, so I guess caching can't really be an issue or could it ?)

Comment: OK. That means that `@include icon('plane', 't', 'IcoMoon');` is not working. Try adding this directly to your SASS file: https://gist.github.com/rdougan/5757918

Comment: Well I added it ot my sass file, sadly it didnt work any better in chrome or safari

Comment: No other idea? Its weird to me that it worked in your video and we can't get it to work in this simple app.

Comment: Add this to your anwser

To see those icons loaded, you need to run the index.html from folder.
Reaching an apache local server will not load those icons for some obscure reasons.

Comment: @Fawar that is incorrect. The icons should display correctly from an server, assuming the permissions on the file is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I've also recently created this new app that will help you to prepare an icons and corresponding SCCS file for your Sencha Touch apps. This has also been tested with Sencha Architect projects.

The README explains the steps for creating icons at the Ico Moon web site and using the tool to convert Ico Moon project files into SCSS for use in Sencha Touch.

- https://github.com/tohagan/sencha-ico-moon